# How can i install python-lzo-1.08?

Tags: python, installation, lzo

I need to install python-lzo-1.08.
When i try to do it from gz-file, i getting error:
`NameError: name 'CURL_DIR' is not defined`
OS: win7
I can't anywhere find windows installer (google taking only gz or broken links to msi/exe).
Maybe anybody have this file? please, share! ( sergiy.panasyuk88@gmail.com )
Or help with error "name 'CURL_DIR' is not defined".

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply install python-lzo on a windows based system.  If you take a look at the windows [install guide](https://bitbucket.org/james_taylor/python-lzo-static/src/63987d89fd1b/lzo-2.03/B/00README.TXT), you will find directions for building python-lzo on your system.

Unless you know that you already have a c/c++ compiler, I would recommend downloading something like [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org) first, installing that, then follow the instructions in the readme linked above.

Answer (score 5):

Check this:

- Python Extension Packages for Windows - Christoph Gohlke : http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-lzo

This web is a treasure for the windows' people :) In that place you can download binary packages, and avoid all the usual installation and compiling.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.